# How to get the Arabic Text (or Unicode) from this strange Encoding in C#

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Really i dont know what this Encoding 
"ÙŠØ¬Ø¨ Ø§Ù„ØªØ­Ù‚Ù‚ Ù…Ù† Ù†Ø¸Ø§Ù… Ø§Ù„Ø­Ù…Ø§ÙŠØ© Ø§Ù„Ø«Ù„Ø§Ø«ÙŠ"

but i know it is Arabic Language

How to convert it to UniCode using C#

i just tried

```
string ArabicString = "ÙŠØ¬Ø¨ Ø§Ù„ØªØ­Ù‚Ù‚ Ù…Ù† Ù†Ø¸Ø§Ù… Ø§Ù„Ø­Ù…Ø§ÙŠØ© Ø§Ù„Ø«Ù„Ø§Ø«ÙŠ";
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ArabicString);
str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```

Comment: Where did you get that encoding? How do you know it is Arabic?

Comment: What the are byte values of the input? (And putting it into a literal string will impose UTF-16 on it: all your code does is encode that into UTF-8: it will not help determine the origin of the data.)

Comment: i get it from a REST JSON API and i know that this API returns arabic message .. i tried Unicode as well doesnt help .. what to do

Comment: The latter two lines of your code are a no-op. You transform an already UTF-16 string into a UTF-8 byte array and then back into the original UTF-16 string. Your chance to properly decode this is when you read the bytes out of the stream from your web service response. That's where you need to know the encoding. Chances are the web response headers tell you which encoding is used.

Comment: it returns in JSON format

Comment: i even dont put it in a string it is already a string .. returned in string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(url, param); where wc is a webclient

Comment: JSON may legally be in many different encodings. Your JSON deserialization process needs to know which one is being used. Post the code that is actually deserializing the http response; that's where the problem lies.

Comment: WebClient.Encoding specifies the encoding used to transmit and receive strings. Make sure it matches what the service returns.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this?

```
str = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```

Comment: .. i tried Unicode as well doesnt help .. what to do

Comment: I do not know `c#` syntax but python `print(bytearray(ArabicString,"cp1252").decode("utf8"))` starts with `يجب التحقق من نظام الحماية الثلاثي` Arabic text… @Mariam

Comment: Likely then all you need is wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 before the call to UploadString. Code page 1252 sounds like you're just using the system default encoding in your webclient.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'm late to the game but this should work. I had similar issues recently and came across this question. This worked for me.
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ArabicString))